# C# List or Array with String and Number

Tags: c#, arrays, c#-4.0, multidimensional-array, arraylist

What is the best method to create an array or a list which contain a string and a number?

With Dictionary it can be done this way:

```
Dictionary < string, int > dict = new Dictionary < string, int > ();
```

but are there better methods with Array or List?

I need it to store IP addresses and coresponding port numbers.

Comment: Are the string and the number supposed to be associated (as in a Dictionary) or are you just trying to hold a generic list of "stuff"?

Comment: You could use a dictionary, or you could create a list of objects. The "best" option depends on your needs and whatever you are comfortable with.

Comment: I need to hold an ip address and the coresponding port number

Comment: @MarioM: In that case, I'd recommend creating an IpAddress struct that has everything you need in it, and making a list of that.

Comment: Questions asking for "the best" without criteria for "better are not really answerable. Asking for "shopping list" of options is not really good for SO either... Consider clarifying your post.

Comment: You may want to look at the [`IPAddress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress(v=vs.110).aspx) class

Comment: @juharr interesting, but my IP addresses are stored as strings in the database and also the `IPAddress` class does not have member for the port number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way depends on your use case.  But here's an easy way.

```
var list = new List<Tuple<string, int>> {
    Tuple.Create("foo", 123),
    Tuple.Create("bar", 234),
};
```

If you want a list of correlated ip addresses and ports, I'd make a dedicated type for it.

```
struct Address {
    public string Ip;
    public int Port;
}

...

var list = new List<Address>();
```

Answer (score 2):

Due to the hashtable it is built upon; a **Dictionary** is the faster way to go if you are going to search the content to find a certain key.

```
var list = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

A List of Key/Value pairs would need to parse each entry, every single "KeyValuePair" that is, to check if it contains a specific key. This will lead to an slightly exponentional performance loss upon adding more and more entries.

```
var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
```